# Ruby On Rails 4 - Serializers not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I am working on building a JSON API using Ruby-On-Rails 4.

To serialize my JSON responses, I use `active_model_serializers` version 0.9.4.

I have an ApiController which inherits from ApplicationController. All my controllers inherit from ApiController.

Here is what ApiController looks like:

```
class Api::ApiController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Serialization
  private

    def respond_with_json(payload)
      render json: payload, root: false, status: 200
    end
end
```

I've created a FriendshipSerializer, associated to Friendship Model, using `rails g serializer friendship`. This generated the following file:

```
class FriendshipSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :image
end
```

Here is the code of `friendships#index` controller action:

```
def index
  friendships = current_user.friendships.order(created_at: "DESC")
  respond_with_json(friendships)
end
```

The problem I am currently encountering is when calling `friendships#index` controller action, it returns a JSON array with all Friendship Model data, while it is supposed to return only ids(according to FriendshipSerializer).

Comment: which version of active_model_serializers?

Comment: I am using "0.9.4"

Comment: what happens if you specify the serializer? https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#arrays

Comment: When I specify a Serializer, it works fine. The things is that I don't want to do this as is not a good practice

Comment: You are right, this is sort of a known issue (autoloading of serializers not working in some cases)

Comment: Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: have you tried : `friendships = current_user.friendships.order(created_at: "DESC").ids`

Comment: This would work if I only want to render ids. The things is that my serializers can evolve in the future..

Comment: maybe this will work : `attribute :id in FriendshipSerializer`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. I've updated my description.

Comment: It finally worked without having to change anything in my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works when the serializers are [explicitly specified](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#arrays), I suspect this is a known issue (autoloading of serializers not working in some cases, which may or may not be a bug as this might be caused by interference from other gems). If you can live with this (or find a workaround), you can continue to work with 0.9 (which is more "battle-tested"), otherwise try to use the current version 0.10. Note that there are some major changes between these versions.

Answer (score 1):

I notice a few spelling inconsistencies in your question. Are you sure the classnames of the model and serializer match?  For example, if your model class is named "Friendship," AMS will look for a serializer named "FriendshipSerializer." If AMS does not find that serializer, I believe it will still render the record's attributes independently of a serializer; so if you've got a "Friendship" model and "FrienshipSerializer" (or vice versa), that could be the problem.

Comment: I didn't make any copy paste from my project code. I've wrote the whole code myself...
I've checked my ruby code & everything is okay